# Tips for reach performance in OpenGL simulations

Tags: performance, opengl, simulation

i would like to know some tips, articles or books about performance in OpenGL based simulations

Comment: If you gave a little more information about your application, you could get some more specific tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [presentation](http://developer.amd.com/media/gpu_assets/PerformanceTuning.pdf) to get you started. It may be AMD but most points still stand.

Also, if you're seriously into OpenGL, there one book that is a [must to have](http://glbook.gamedev.net/moglgp/).

But probably there's one golden rule -- read the [OpenGL 3.2 specifications](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20091207.pdf), and DON'T USE anything that is marked as DEPRECATED. That alone will save you from most OpenGL bottlenecks.

A handful of general tips:

- reduce the amount of [draw calls](http://blogs.technet.com/torgo3000/archive/2007/06/14/performance-art-2-when-is-a-draw-call-not-a-draw-call.aspx) (calls to the graphics hardware)
- reduce as much as possible texture changes (use [texture atlases](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/20060126/ivanov_01.shtml))
- use efficient data to graphics card solutions (preferably [Vertex Buffer Object](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html)'s and [Framebuffer Object](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)'s)
- measure performance, use [profilers](http://www.gremedy.com/) to find the bottlenecks!
- do what calculaions you can on the GPU using [shaders](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/)

Comment: The "must to have" 404'd :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing it already, be sure to use vertex buffer objects.  If complex shading is slowing you down, consider a deferred shading model.